# Responsive menu not working for small screens

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a responsive navigation menu. I found some tutorials online and after finding one that I liked the style of, I followed the directions to create it on my website, but I can't seem to get a couple features working.

1: I can't get the hover effect to work that adds a bottom border to the icons/links to help accent the one that is in focus.

2: When getting down to a screen size that is below 32.5em (519px), the menu is supposed to become a single column menu that folds up. The menu does become a single column, but it doesn't fold up into a button like it is supposed to. It keeps displaying all of the links which takes up a lot of vertical space.

```
Here is a jsFiddle of my project so you can see what I have so far:
https://jsfiddle.net/4Ljs1bfn/1/
```

Comment: `@media screen and (max-width: 518px){ /* css here */}`

Comment: I already have `@media (max-width: 32.5em){ /* with css */}`. 32.5em = 518px.

Comment: I was under the impression that doing it by window width would cover both browser resizing and device screen sizes so thats what I was going for.

Comment: I know. if you looked at the jsfiddle link, you would see that I have a lot of css already written in which I am applying hover, active, focus, etc. Im not asking for you to write it, I'm asking for help with figuring out why mine doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the js detection that the example uses.

1. Add `class="no-js"` to your body element.
2. Then on load, set `document.body.className = "js"` (or equivalent).

This will enable the menu.

For the `:hover` problem, you need the `class="no-touch"` on your body element (then remove it using js if a touchscreen is detected).

Another thing: You have a html error at `<a href="..."">` on line ~8 (that extra " at the end).

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4Ljs1bfn/2/. You still have some css issues, but I assume you can fix them yourself.